# C# openGL Tao.Framework - синхронное движение объектов

Tags: c#, opengl

как задать перемещения объектов (пирамида и куб) так, чтобы они не заходили друг на друга и двигались синхронно? То есть, мне надо сделать так, чтобы дом двигался (куб и пирамида) одновременно по диагонали куба. У меня сейчас дом вращается, а если делаю так, чтобы он двигался относительно диагонали куба, то крыша и основа двигаются относительно своих точек. Может быть, возможно как-то сгруппировать два объекта в OpenGL?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    private bool textureIsLoad = false;
    public float rti, speed = 1,rotX,rotY,rotZ;
    public string texture_name = "";
    public int imageId = 0;

    public string url;
    public uint mGlTextureObject = 0;
    public uint mGlTextureObject2 = 0;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AnT.InitializeContexts();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // ініціалізація бібліотеки Glut
        Glut.glutInit();
        // ініціалізація режиму екрана
        Glut.glutInitDisplayMode(Glut.GLUT_RGB | Glut.GLUT_DOUBLE);

        // ініціалізація OpenGl
        Il.ilInit();
        Il.ilEnable(Il.IL_ORIGIN_SET);

        // очиска екрана (RGBA) 
        Gl.glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 1);

        // порт виводу
        Gl.glViewport(0, 0, AnT.Width, AnT.Height);

        // активація проекційної матриці
        Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);
        // очистка матриці
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();

        // перспектива
        Glu.gluPerspective(30, AnT.Width / AnT.Height, 1, 100);

        // обєктно видова матриця 
        Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW);
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();

        // початкові настройкиOpenGL
        Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHTING);
        Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHT0);

        // активація таймера
        RenderTimer.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void RenderTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // промальовка
        Draw();
    }

    private void Draw()
    {
        loadImage();
        loadImage2();
        // якщо текстура завантажена
        if (textureIsLoad)
        {
            // очистка буферів кольору та глибини
            Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | Gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            Gl.glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 1);
            // очищение вибраної матриці
            Gl.glLoadIdentity();

            // вкл режим текстурування
            Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            // ідентифікатор на текстурування mGlTextureObject
            Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mGlTextureObject);

            // зберігаємо матрицю
            Gl.glPushMatrix();

            Gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, -0.5f, -7.0f);
            // поворот
            Gl.glRotatef(rti, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);//рух

            // рисуєм полігон
            Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);

            // малюєм куб
            //верх куба
            Gl.glLoadIdentity();
            // перед
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); // Низ лліво
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);  // Низ право
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   // Верх право
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  // Верх ліво

            // Зад 
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);// Низ право
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f); // Верх право
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);  // Верх ліво
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); // Низ ліво

            // Верх
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f); // Верх ліво
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  // Низ ліво
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   // Низ право
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);  // Верх право

            // Низ
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);// Верх право
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); // Верх ліво
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);  // Низ ліво
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); // Низ право

            // Права
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); // Низ право
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);  // Верх право
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   // Верх ліво
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);  // Низ ліво

            // Ліва
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);// Низ ліво
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); // Низ право
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  // Верх право
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f); // Верх ліво
            Gl.glEnd();
            Gl.glPopMatrix();
            Gl.glFlush();

            // повертаємо матрицю
            Gl.glPopMatrix();


            //піраміда        
            // замінюємо ідентифікатор текстури mGlTextureObject
            Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mGlTextureObject2);
            Gl.glPushMatrix();
            Gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 1.5f, -7.0f);//розміщення піраміди
            Gl.glRotatef(rti, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);//рух

            Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_TRIANGLES);
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);  Gl.glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // верх піраміди
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); // ліва
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); // права

            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);//верх права
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); // ліво (права) 
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); // права(право)

            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // низ ззаду
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); // ліва ззаду
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); // права ззаду

            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // верх ліво
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); // ліва ліво
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); Gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); // права ліво
            Gl.glEnd();

            Gl.glPopMatrix();
            Gl.glFlush();
            Gl.glDisable(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            rti += speed;//зміна шв руху
            // оновлюємо елемент зі сценою
            AnT.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void loadImage()
    {

            // зображення з ідентифікатором imageId
            Il.ilGenImages(1, out imageId);
            // вибираєм зображення
            Il.ilBindImage(imageId);

            // адреса
            url = @"C:\Users\paliy\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Grafica_2\text_stina.jpg";  


            // загружаєм
            if (Il.ilLoadImage(url))
            {
                int width = Il.ilGetInteger(Il.IL_IMAGE_WIDTH);
                int height = Il.ilGetInteger(Il.IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT);

                // визначаєм число біт на піксель
                int bitspp = Il.ilGetInteger(Il.IL_IMAGE_BITS_PER_PIXEL);

                switch (bitspp) // від кількості біт
                {
                        //  GL_RGB або GL_RGBA
                    case 24:
                        mGlTextureObject = MakeGlTexture(Gl.GL_RGB, Il.ilGetData(), width, height);
                        break;
                    case 32:
                        mGlTextureObject = MakeGlTexture(Gl.GL_RGBA, Il.ilGetData(), width, height);
                        break;
                }

                textureIsLoad = true;
                // очищуємо память
                Il.ilDeleteImages(1, ref imageId);
            }
    }

    private static uint MakeGlTexture(int Format, IntPtr pixels, int w, int h)
    {
        // ідентифікатор текстурного обєкта
        uint texObject;

        // генеруємо текстурний обєкт
        Gl.glGenTextures(1, out texObject);

        // режим упаковки пікселів
        Gl.glPixelStorei(Gl.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

        // привязка до створеної текстури
        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texObject);

        // режим фільтрації і повтору текстури
        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, Gl.GL_REPEAT);
        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, Gl.GL_REPEAT);
        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);
        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);
        Gl.glTexEnvf(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, Gl.GL_REPLACE);

        // RGB або RGBA 
        switch (Format)
        {
            case Gl.GL_RGB:
                Gl.glTexImage2D(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, Gl.GL_RGB, w, h, 0, Gl.GL_RGB, Gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
                break;

            case Gl.GL_RGBA:
                Gl.glTexImage2D(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, Gl.GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, Gl.GL_RGBA, Gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
                break;
        }

        // повертаємо ідентифікатор текстури

        return texObject;
    }

    //черепиця
    private void loadImage2()
    {
        // imageId
        Il.ilGenImages(1, out imageId);
        // вибироаєм збр
        Il.ilBindImage(imageId);

        // адрес
        string url = @"C:\Users\paliy\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Grafica_2\texture_top.jpg";

        if (Il.ilLoadImage(url))
        {
            int width = Il.ilGetInteger(Il.IL_IMAGE_WIDTH);
            int height = Il.ilGetInteger(Il.IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT);

            int bitspp = Il.ilGetInteger(Il.IL_IMAGE_BITS_PER_PIXEL);

            switch (bitspp) 
            {
                case 24:
                    mGlTextureObject2 = MakeGlTexture(Gl.GL_RGB, Il.ilGetData(), width, height);
                    break;
                case 32:
                    mGlTextureObject2 = MakeGlTexture(Gl.GL_RGBA, Il.ilGetData(), width, height);
                    break;
            }

            textureIsLoad = true;
            Il.ilDeleteImages(1, ref imageId);


        }
    }

    private static uint MakeGlTexture2(int Format, IntPtr pixels, int w, int h)
    {
        uint texObject;

        Gl.glGenTextures(2, out texObject);

        Gl.glPixelStorei(Gl.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texObject);

        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, Gl.GL_REPEAT);
        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, Gl.GL_REPEAT);
        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);
        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);
        Gl.glTexEnvf(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, Gl.GL_REPLACE);

        switch (Format)
        {
            case Gl.GL_RGB:
                Gl.glTexImage2D(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, Gl.GL_RGB, w, h, 0, Gl.GL_RGB, Gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
                break;

            case Gl.GL_RGBA:
                Gl.glTexImage2D(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, Gl.GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, Gl.GL_RGBA, Gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
                break;
        }

        return texObject;
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnStart.Text = "Go";
        //запуск таймера
        RenderTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void btnPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //зупинка таймера
        RenderTimer.Enabled = false;
        btnStart.Text = "Continue";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        speed = (float)trackBar1.Value;
        label2.Text = Convert.ToString(speed);
    }     
}
```

---

[image]

Вот пример, как по отдельности использую к пирамиде и куба Gl.glRotatef();

Comment: Попробуйте использовать [Display Lists](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/version1.1/glspec1.1/node123.html)

Comment: не получаеца...( читал что надо делать перемещения обектов, и изменения их угла относительно X,Y,Z. но как ето прощитать(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо применить общую трансформацию к обоим объектам. Причем не изменяя их локальных позиций. Это делается просто домножением матрицы. В вашем коде это может выглядеть так:

```
        // очистка буферів кольору та глибини
        Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | Gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gl.glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 1);
        // очищение вибраної матриці
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();

        // вкл режим текстурування
        Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        // ідентифікатор на текстурування mGlTextureObject
        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mGlTextureObject);

        // Ваш поворот
        Gl.glRotatef(rti, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);//рух

        // зберігаємо матрицю
        Gl.glPushMatrix();

        Gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, -0.5f, -7.0f);

        // Тут поворот не нужен.

        // рисуєм полігон
        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
        ....
        Gl.glEnd();
        Gl.glPopMatrix();
        Gl.glFlush();

        // повертаємо матрицю
        //Gl.glPopMatrix(); Возможно это лишнее

        //піраміда        
        // замінюємо ідентифікатор текстури mGlTextureObject
        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mGlTextureObject2);
        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 1.5f, -7.0f);//розміщення піраміди

        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_TRIANGLES);
        ...
        Gl.glPopMatrix();
        Gl.glFlush();

        ...
```

Ещё мне кажется у вас один Gl.glPopMatrix(); лишний. Количество Gl.glPopMatrix(); должно быть равно Gl.glPushMatrix().

ПС. Я смотрю, что вы используете старый OpenGL. Рекомендую использовать OpenGL 3+.

Comment: а не подскажете как сделать движение обєкта по диагонали куба?

Comment: Видимо вместо трансформации Gl.glRotatef(rti, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);//рух необходимо применить трансформацию Gl.glTranslatef(step, step, 0.0f); step надо увеличивать для каждого рендера.

Comment: у меня получалось сделать трансформацию по отдельности к пирамиди и куба... используя Gl.glRotatef(); а сейчас когда применяю ко целому обєкту почемуто не получаеца(( (